# What is the most efficient way to import data from an API and loop over it in an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-manipulation

I'm working on a brand new iPhone app in Objective-C and I want to make sure it's built ford tough, from the bottom up. Since I have the luxury of building from scratch.

What is the most efficient way (smallest memory footprint created) to make an http request to a JSON API and store the data for manipulation within the app?

Comment: Look at RestKit and Core Data.

Comment: Yes "JSON" is the best approach in terms of having response from the server and it's easy to maintain an array of your response and use it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web service API supports JSON, then use JSON.

JSON parsers will parse the JSON text (as received in the response data from the request) and "convert" it into a corresponding hierarchy of Foundation objects - the "representation". That's quite easy to accomplish and it's a matter of a few lines of code.

From your description, network related code should be implemented via `NSURLConnection` using the delegate approach, which is also asynchronous. You must use the delegate approach, when you need to customize authentication and handling of certificates.

For moderately large data sets, you may certainly choose one of the *viable* third party network libraries. They will support customization of authentication and handling of certificates, too.

Regarding your question how to process the data:

Once you have the Foundation object representing your resource - which may be for example, a User, or a list of Users, etc., you take this Foundation object and create or update your corresponding "Models". "Models" are the representation of your "data", say a User or a list of Users, usually a custom class, possibly a Core Data Managed Object.

This simple approach will work for almost all use cases, when the data is "small".

When it comes to "large" data sets, this approach will not work anymore. A rule of thumb: the amount of memory allocated for the Foundation objects is about 5 to 8 times the size in bytes of the JSON text. For example, a 30 MByte JSON will require roughly 200 MByte for the representation. Even on modern devices, this will likely cause memory warnings, given that there are other allocations as well.

A solution to process "very large" data sets, is to process the data in chunks. That is, use *many* possibly *different dedicated* and *specialized* "tasks" whose work load requires only a *small* data set. Let those tasks run in parallel *where possible*.  (I need to stop here ;))

In order to persist your data, you may directly utilize *SQLite*, or you may want to use *Core Data* - which uses SQLite as backing store.

If you simply want to fetch or insert objects from a database, which is a large data set, you may consider to use SQLite - instead of utilizing Core Data for performance reasons.

You would want to use Core Data if you have edit, create, delete, merge and search operations for your "Model" objects which will be executed via the UI by the user, or executed through other tasks which display the result in the UI.

Note: Core Data is not a database.

One word to third party network libraries:

I haven't seen any yet which offers the flexibility that I would like to have in certain use cases. And more important, none is "scaleable". That is, when you have large data sets (>10MByte) your application starts to become suboptimal - performance wise and regarding memory foot-print. With large and very large data sets, your app may choke.

Most of these libraries will accumulate the whole response data in a `NSMutableData` object and wont't let you easily process the received chunks as they arrive. The workaround is to use a temporary file - which requires additional elaborated code in your app. Note, that you may get memory warnings after trying to parse a 30 MByte JSON file - which takes 7 seconds to transmit over Wifi.

Having data sets in the range of several MBytes, isn't the usual case, though.